# ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard not working in private mode

Tags: applepay

I have implemented Apple Pay on my website. If the payment method is configured it shows 'Checkout with Apple Pay' and if the payment method not configured then it shows 'Setup Apple Pay'.

I am  using `ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard()` to check if the payment mode is configured or not.

This implementation is normally working correctly on Safari.
But when I run the application in Private (incognito) mode, it does not work as expected.

In Private mode `ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard()` always returns true irrespective of whether Payment Method setup is done or not. So it always shows me 'Checkout with Apple Pay'.

Any Suggestions, please?